# How to bypass CSS Font-Variant-Ligatures?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, webfonts

on my wordpress website theme, there is a CSS property (font-variant-ligatures) by default added that I cannot find and remove but I need to disable or bypass this property using any other css file with !important.

Actully, this property is creating chaos in my font that font characters gets smashed in each other. When I turn off this CSS property in Chrome Browser's Inspector, then font looks good.

Currently it is written as in Wordpress CSS:

```
font-variant-ligatures: none;
```

I cannot delete this property, but I can override it with a better one by adding some other line in another CSS file. Can you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding this line into another new CSS file for overriding:

```
font-variant-ligatures: normal !important;
```